# Skip frames in video playback with MediaExtractor and MediaCodec

Tags: java, android, video, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I'm using MediaExtractor/MediaCodec to decode a video and render it to a TextureView. As a template, I've used the code from: https://github.com/vecio/MediaCodecDemo/blob/master/src/io/vec/demo/mediacodec/DecodeActivity.java

I'd like to be able to playback the video at 2x speed. Luckily, the media encoding/decoding is fast enough so that I can accomplish this by letting the MediaCodec decode every frame, and then only render every other frame to the screen. However this doesn't feel like a great solution, particularly if you want to increase playback by an arbitrary value. For example, at 10x speeds, the Codec is not able to decode frames fast enough to playback every 10th frame at 30 fps.

So instead I'd like control playback by calling MediaExtractor.advance() multiple times to skip frames that don't need to be decoded. For example:

```
        ...
        mDecoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, sampleSize, mExtractor.getSampleTime(), 0);
        for (i = 0; i < playbackSpeedIncrease; i++) {
               mExtractor.advance();
        }
        ...
```

With this code, in theory the extractor should only extract every *nth* frame, where *n* is defined by the variable 'playbackSpeedIncrease'. For example, if *n* = 5, this should advance past frames 1-4 and only extract frame 5.

However, this does not work in practice. When I run this code, the image rendered to the screen is distorted: [image]

Does anyone know why this is? Any suggestions for better ways to playback videos at an arbitrary speed increase?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't generally do this with AVC video.

The encoded video has "key" (or "sync" or "I") frames that hold full images, but the frames between key frames hold "diffs" from the previous frames.  You can find some articles at wikipedia about video encoding methods, e.g. [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter_frame).  You're getting nasty video because you skipped a key frame and now the diffs are being computed against the wrong image.

If you've ever seen video fast-forward smoothly but fast-reverse clunkily, e.g. on a TiVo, this is why: the video decoder plays forward quickly, but in reverse it just plays the I-frames, holding them on screen long enough to get the desired rate.  At "faster" forward/reverse it evens out because the device is just playing I-frames.  You can do something similar by watching for the `SAMPLE_FLAG_SYNC` flag on the frames you get from MediaExtractor.

In general you're limited to either playing the video as fast as the device can decode it, or playing just the key frames.  (If you know enough about the layout of a specific video in a specific encoding you may be able to do better, e.g. play the I and P but not the B, but I'm not sure that's even possible in AVC.)

The frequency of I frames is determined by the video encoder.  It tends to be one or two per second, but if you get videos from different sources then you can expect the GOP size (group-of-pictures, i.e. how many frames there are between I-frames) to vary.